# Adding two-step authentication to DotNetNuke 7.x Login

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

We have recently been compelled by our Auditing department to add a secondary step to one of our DNN installations. The version we are on right now is 7.2.1.

Initially I thought setting the 'requiresQuestionAndAnswer' attribute to true in the web.config would solve my problem. However, the question and answer is not required for the Login, but only for the password reset and the registration.

Audit is requiring that it be part of the Login process itself.

Does version 7 or 8 of DNN (Community or Professional) have this kind of customization for the Login process? It does not have to be only Question & Answer, it could be a PIN or some other piece of data.

If not is there a 3rd party module that does? I have looked around, but haven't seen something that fits my needs exactly.

Thanks for any help or information you can give.

Answer (score 0):

The only two factor type of authentication I have ever seen in DNN is home grown/brewed.  Afraid you are most likely going to have to work with a developer to modify the login control to handle this for you.